# get.shortest.paths em grafo temporal

Tags: r, grafo

Estou usando a biblioteca "igraph" e estou trabalhando com grafos dinâmicos.
Tenho o seguinte grafo:

VertexFrom VertexTo TimeStart TimeStop

a c 1 1

a d 2 2

b d 2 2

c d 3 3

d b 3 3

Ou seja, v1 está ligado a v2 no tempo x ao y.

Exemplo. No primeiro intervalor [0,1] 
meu grafo estará assim

a ---------  c

b (not edge) d

So tenho uma aresta de 'a' para 'c'. E assim por diante...

Estou usando a função get.shortest.paths para calcular o menor caminho temporal.

Ex.:

get.shortest.paths(g, 'a 3', 'b 3', mode="all", weights=E(g)$HopCost)

Irá calcular o caminho de a para b no intervalo de tempo[3,3]. No intervalo [3,3] esse caminho não existe, mas a função me retornar:

a 3 a 2 d 2 b 2 b 3

Ou seja, ela volta no tempo para achar um caminho. De 'a 3' ela voltou para 'a 2' foi para 'd 2', depois 'b 2' e finalmente para 'b 3'. Alguém sabe como modificar para que ela não volte? Nesse caso, quero que ela calcule, se existir, somente o menor caminho no tempo 'x' ao tempo 'y', sem voltar no tempo. No exemplo acima o resultado seria zero, pois não existe caminho.

Comment: Como você está importando o grafo para o `igraph`? Até onde sei, não é possível criar grafos dinâmicos com essa biblioteca. Você teria que criar 3 diferentes grafos (3 snapshots) e calcular `get.shortest.path` para cada grafo individualmente.

Comment: A partir dessa biblioteca www.benjaminblonder.org/timeorderednetworks/